# macOS Docker Desktop default driver?

Tags: mac, docker

I'm trying to find out which driver the Docker Desktop is now using as default for macOS. Feels like I've looked everywhere for an answer but came up empty. Does it still use VirtualBox or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Comment: What do you mean by driver?